# Delete QStringList in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management, memory-leaks

In Qt I understand that if you create an object that inherits from QObject and set it's parent, then the parent is responsible for deleting the children. I also understand that if you create objects on the stack that they are deleted when they go out of scope.

I'm not wrapping my head around the case where I want to explicitly delete items in a QStringList ( or any QList ) and then the list itself.

Consider if I create a QStringList and populate it like below:

```
QStringList multiPartPortionList;
multiPartPortionList = multiPartPortion.split(QRegExp("[\r\n]"),QString::SkipEmptyParts);
```

Then I do stuff with it and call this method in attempt to explicitly delete the items contained within the list and then the list itself:

```
void MyClass::deleteList(QStringList list) {

    // Now cleanup
    QStringList *delList = new QStringList(list);
    int numObjects = delList->count();
    for (int i=0; i < numObjects; i++)
        delete (new QString(list.takeAt(0)));
    delList->clear();
    delete delList;
    delList = 0;

}
```

I can't call qDeleteall(list) because it expects a pointer, and I also can't do just do:

```
delete list;
```

Since it errors with **'argument given to 'delete', expected pointer'**, expecting a pointer.

I get segmentation faults with:

```
void MyClass::deleteList(QStringList list) {

    // Now cleanup
    QStringList *delList = &list; // <--- Seg fault with this
    int numObjects = delList->count();
    for (int i=0; i < numObjects; i++)
        delete (new QString(list.takeAt(0)));
    delList->clear();
    delete delList;
    delList = 0;

}
```

I also get segmentation faults with:

```
void MyClass::deleteList(QStringList list) {

    // Now cleanup
    QStringList *delList = &list;
    int numObjects = delList->count();
    for (int i=0; i < numObjects; i++)
        delete &(list.takeAt(0)); // <--- Seg fault with this
    delList->clear();
    delete delList;
    delList = 0;

}
```

And then I also get segmentation faults with:

```
void MyClass::deleteList(QStringList list) {

    // Now cleanup
    QStringList *delList = new QStringList(list);
    int numObjects = delList->count();
    for (int i=0; i < numObjects; i++)
        delete (new QString(list.takeAt(0)));
    delList->clear();
    delete delList;
    delList = 0;
    delete &list; // <--- Seg fault with this

}
```

I don't think this is quite, or even close, to being right. How can I best achieve what I want - that is to explicitly delete all items in a list and then the list itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `QStringList list` gets deleted automagically at the end of the function. No need to worry about deleting pointers here.

In the same manner,

```
QStringList *delList = new QStringList(list);
```

should be

```
QStringList delList = QStringList(list);
```

better yet:

```
QStringList delList = list;
```

You should read about automatic storage and RAII. In your code, `new` and `delete` are superfluous.

To remove an element in the list, use [removeAt](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qlist.html#removeAt). This has nothing to do with deleting.

I also suggest that you get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) before continuing in C++.